# Karate - Is there a way to get data from DB in Examples section of scenario outline?

Tags: karate

There is a requirement every time I run my automation I first need to get list of data from DB (as it is very dynamic) and put it in Examples section of scenario outline and use it running the feature file

I have used scenario outline as same scenario needs to be run for multiple data set .

So can you suggest if there is a way for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try the dynamic scenario outline introduced in 0.9.X: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

```
Examples:
    | getDataFromDb() |
```

Note that there is an open bug for logs and a large number of rows: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/660

Else the normal looping over a second feature which you already know will work: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests